# SQL Query creates buttons that one can click to 'hopefully' change DIV

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am failing hardcore with describing this but here it goes..

I have home.php, pretty much just:

```
<body>
<div id='leftColumn'>
  <?php include ('includes/roomQuery.php') 
</div>                                        
</body>
```

Now,
roomQuery.php echos my sql column 'room_name' from table 'rooms' as follows:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"room.php?room=$roomName\">$roomName</a></td>";
```

Any of the room links will take me to room.php and populate the page with more queries respective to $roomName via $_GET.

room.php is basically:

```
$get = $_GET['room'];
$query
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $query
```

This is working perfectly for what it is.

====================================

however, I am trying to make my site flow better, and have been trying out the jQuery .load function.  So far I have changed roomQuery.php to:

```
echo "<td><button>$roomName</button></td>";
```

here is my jQuery to replace home.php #page with room.php #page:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#page").load("room.php #page",function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
                if(statusTxt=="success")
                    alert("Success");
                if(statusTxt=="error")
                    alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
            });
        });
    });
```

When I click any of the buttons that roomQuery.php spits out, it replaces #page perfectly but I cannot grasp how/if I can send $_GET['room'] to room.php so that when #page is loaded, the information is still respective to the room I clicked on.  If I change jQuery to

```
$("#page").load("room.php?room=CL%20124 #page"
```

Then #page is populated with the data specifically respective to room CL 124.  Is it possible to post the button text that is output from roomsQuery.php to room.php #page when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can [pass data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745384/2812842) into the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) call as the second parameter.

Firstly, you need to work out how to get the room ID from the DOM into your jQuery call, maybe you could use a data attribute on the button element like this:

```
<button data-room-id="123">Click me</button>
```

Then use jQuery like this:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    // define your room ID here, however you do it
    var your_room = $(this).data('room-id');
    $("#page").load(
        "room.php #page",
        {
            room: your_room
        },
        function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
            if(statusTxt=="success")
                alert("Success");
            if(statusTxt=="error")
                alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
        }
    );
});
```

**Edit:** just noticed that you might actually be using the button's value as your room ID, if so, use this definition:

```
var your_room = $(this).val();
```

If you're expecting spaces or non-alpha numeric characters in this value, you might want to consider [URL encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6544603/2812842) it before you send it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  I am plugging this is in now and seeing what I can work out.

Comment: So i have verified that changing the button to include data-room-id works.  The buttons are populating with the data set as their respective $roomName.  However, when I click the button it is still populating #page with queries from all the rooms.  Its not adding the ?room=$roomName to room.php.  do I need to modify how the data is being interpreted by jQuery?

Comment: When you provide data to `.load()` as an object (which I've done above), the HTTP method is changed to POST instead of GET. You'll need to either pass a string like `data: "room=" + your_room` or change your PHP superglobal from `$_GET` to `$_POST`

Comment: using var roomName = $( this ).val();  worked perfect.  thanks a ton